# ajaxSubmit causes incorrect character decoding

Tags: html, unicode, asp-classic, character-encoding, jquery-forms-plugin

Consider the following simple Asp page - a form with one text input and a submit button:

```
<%
    response.write(Request.Form("test") & "<br/>")
%>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script>

<form action="test.asp" method="post" id="form" name="form" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <input type="text" name="test" />
    <input type="submit" id="sub" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" />
    $('#form').submit(function () {
        $('#form').ajaxSubmit({
            success : function(responseText){

            },
            error : function(){
            }
        });

        return false;
    }); 
</script>
```

Using the value `®`:

If I submit the form *without* ajax (not using the bottom script block), the response is `®`. The data gets encoded as `test=%AE`.

If I submit the form *with* ajax (using the bottom script block), the response is `Â®`. The data gets encoded as `test=%C2%AE`.

Since `%C2%AE` is the valid encoding for `®`, is this a vbscript issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I submit the form without ajax (not using the bottom script block), the response is ®. The data gets encoded as test=%AE.

This is because of the `accept-charset="ISO-8859-1"`. `ajaxSubmit`, on the other hand, always uses UTF-8, ignoring any `accept-charset`. (This is probably because limitations on AJAX mean that any other encoding will break in some scenarios).

I suggest removing the `accept-charset` attribute (which doesn't work like it should in IE anyway) and serving the page [explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39d1w2xf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as UTF-8. This should get rid of the `Â®` problem.

Comment: Yeah, I started writing the question before I figured out that the ajaxSubmit encoded it in UTF-8 and after I did, didn't reword the question to be "why is ASP decoding a UTF-8 string as ACII?" Yesterday, I couldn't for the life of me get it to decode that as one character instead of two (setting the page encoding et al) - this morning, I can't for the life of me get it to reproduce the behavior I saw yesterday - its decoding correctly even if I set the page encoding and accept-charset to be ISO-8859-1. On a related note, I hate maintaining legacy classic ASP cruft :P